# Why xml tag name not opening <?xml-stylesheet version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" type="text/xsl" href="CadgrafNITF.xsl"?>

Tags: xml, xslt

Why is the xml tag not opening in the browser when an xml start line

```
<?xml-stylesheet version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" type="text/xsl" href="CadgrafNITF.xsl"?>
```

if it is like this it is opening properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

First one shows output like below: only the value not the tag name but the tag names are available while inspecting the page in browser

```
 CADGRAF (c) Copyright 2014 CADGRAF, all rights reserved Not for use outside
 the India 1006 006Parthiban 2013-12-26T00:00:00 Daily Thanthi CE City Edition 
 Bangalore  2013-12-06T00:00:00 5 01 செய்திகள் 01 செய்தி Please Specify notes 
 if any N/A N/A
 கரும்பு விலை பிரச்சினை விவசாயிகளுடன் 9ந்தேதி ஆலோசனை முதல்மந்திரி 
 சித்தராமையா தகவல் பெங்-க-ளூர், டிச.6 முதல்&மந்-திரி சித்-த-ரா-மையா
 பெங்-க-ளூ-ரில் நேற்று நிரு-பர்க-ளுக்கு பேட்டி அளித்-தார். அப்-போது
 அவர் கூறி-ய-தா-வது:& கரும்-புக்கு நிர்-ண-யிக்கப்-பட்ட விலைக்கு
 ஆட்-சே-பனை தெரி-வித்து சுப்-ரீம் கோர்ட்டை சர்க்கரை ஆலை 
 உரி-மை-யா-ளர்கள் அணுகி உள்-ள-னர். அதே நேரத்-தில் கரும்பு விலையை
 இன்-னும் அதி-க-ரிக்க உத்-த-ர-விட வேண்-டும் என்று கோரி கரும்பு 
 விவ-சா-யி-களும் கோர்ட்-டில் மனு செய்து உள்-ள-னர். இந்த பிரச்-சி-னைக்கு
 தீர்வு காணும் வகை-யில், வரு-கிற 9&ந்தேதி சர்க்கரை ஆலை உரிமையாளர்கள் 
 மற்-றும் கரும்பு விவ-சா-யி-களு-டன் ஆலோ-சனை நடத்-தப்-பட உள்ளது. 
 கரும்பு விவ-சா-யி-கள் பிரச்சினைகள் குறித்து விவாதிப்பதற்காக கரும்பு
 விளையும் மாநில முதல்&மந்-தி-ரி-களு-டன் பிர-த-மர் மன்-மோ-கன் சிங்
 இன்று (வெள்-ளிக்கி-ழமை) ஆலோ-சனை நடத்த உள்-ளார். இந்த கூட்-டத்-தில்
 கரும்பு விவ-சா-யி-கள் பிரச்-சி-னைக்கு தீர்வு காணப்-ப-டும். 
 இவ்-வாறு முதல்மந்-திரி சித்-த-ரா-மையா கூறி-னார்.
```

Comment: Why Tamil news is posted here that too regarding Sugar Cane is that related to question in anyway..!

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian Please explain the meaning and the purpose of your edit.

Answer (score 1):

The two constructs look similar but they are in fact different things entirely and serve different purposes.

`<?xml ...?>` is an "XML declaration" which simply signals that this is an XML file using a particular character encoding. The XML declaration is optional but if it appears at all then it *must* be the very first thing in the file, without even whitespace before it.

`<?anything-apart-from-xml ...?>` is called a *processing instruction* and can appear anywhere in the document, and it becomes a node in the document tree structure. How a particular PI is interpreted depends on the application.

In particular, the PI `<?xml-stylesheet ...?>` tells a browser to load the specified stylesheet, apply it to the document, and then render the result of the transformation as if it were HTML, instead of showing the original XML tree. So in order to say why the output looks like that we'd have to see the stylesheet too.

My guess would be that the stylesheet is outputting some sort of non-HTML XML structure and the browser is rendering elements it doesn't recognise as if they were unstyled inline HTML tags like `<span>`, but I'd have to see the stylesheet to be sure.